# How can I sort a vector by its computed values?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have the following

```
use enum_iterator::IntoEnumIterator;

#[derive(Debug, IntoEnumIterator, PartialEq)]
pub enum ResistorColor {
    Black, Blue, Brown, Green,
    Grey, Orange, Red, Violet,
    White, Yellow,
}

pub fn color_to_value(_color: ResistorColor) -> usize {
    //convert a color to a numerical representation
    match _color {
        ResistorColor::Black => 0,
        ResistorColor::Brown => 1,
        ResistorColor::Red => 2,
        ResistorColor::Orange => 3,
        ResistorColor::Yellow => 4,
        ResistorColor::Green => 5,
        ResistorColor::Blue => 6,
        ResistorColor::Violet => 7,
        ResistorColor::Grey => 8,
        ResistorColor::White => 9
    }
}

pub fn value_to_color_string(value: usize) -> String {
    match value {
        0 => "Black".to_string(),
        1 => "Brown".to_string(),
        2 => "Red".to_string(),
        3 => "Orange".to_string(),
        4 => "Yellow".to_string(),
        5 => "Green".to_string(),
        6 => "Blue".to_string(),
        7 => "Violet".to_string(),
        8 => "Grey".to_string(),
        9 => "White".to_string(),
        _ => "Invalid".to_string()
    }
}

pub fn colors() -> Vec<ResistorColor> {
    //reorder the colors to be in order of the value
    let mut colors: Vec<ResistorColor> = ResistorColor::into_enum_iter().collect();
    colors.sort_by(|a, b| color_to_value(a).cmp(&color_to_value(b)));
    colors
}
```

Currently this is giving me a mismatched types error, saying:

```
"expected enum 'ResistorColor', found '&ResistorColor'."
```

I think I understand this message, as the parameter will be only the color, ie "Black, Brown" as opposed to "ResistorColor::Black, ResistorColor::Brown"

How do I resolve this and sort the vector?

Comment: The parameter `a` you get from `sort_by` is a `&ResistorColor`, a.k.a. a *reference*, while `color_to_value` expects `ResistorColor`, not a reference. It has nothing to do with whether the enum variants are qualified with the enum name or not.

Comment: @kmdreko I appreciate the response.. How can I then pass ResistorColor if all I have in the context is a reference?

Comment: Also, after applying the first fix from kmdreko’s answer, note that you can write `colors.sort_by_key(color_to_value)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either change your function to accept by reference, there's no need for it to take ownership:

```
pub fn color_to_value(color: &ResistorColor) -> usize {
                          // ^
    ...
}
```

Or, as is common with simple enums like this, you can implement `Copy` so you can just dereference `a` and `b` to get values:

```
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, IntoEnumIterator, PartialEq)]
             // ^^^^^^^^^^^
pub enum ResistorColor {
    ...
}

colors.sort_by(|a, b| color_to_value(*a).cmp(&color_to_value(*b)));
                                  // ^                       ^
```

Answer (score 1):

A shorter way to implement the sort function is:

```
colors.sort_by_key(|a| color_to_value(*a))
```